# Saving New items in a datagrid to database

Tags: c#, xaml

For my `Datagrid`, Items can be entered on the last row, when filled it autogenerates a new row. Using MVVM, I bind my `Datagrid` to a names contact table. If I were to enter more values, how do I save it to the database?

```
public string info {get; set;}
using (var ctx = DB.Get())
{
    Contacts = BindableCollection<Contact>
        (ctx.Contacts.Select(x => new contact { info = x.info }));
}
info = Contacts.info;
```

XAML side of things:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Contact Info" Binding="{Binding Info}" />
```